# angular.isDefined() vs obj.hasOwnProperty()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object that may or may not have a status. When using the angular.js framework which would be more appropriate. What are the advantages and disadvantages of both.

```
var checkStatus = function(item){
    if(angular.isDefined(item.status){
        //do something
    }
    //VS.
    if(item.hasOwnProperty('status')){
       //do something
    }
}
checkStatus(item);
```

Comment: The difference between the two is that `item.hasOwnProperty('status')` would return `true` for `{status: undefined}`, and Angular would return `true` if `status` was defined anywhere on the prototype chain. So, I guess it depends on your exact use case.

Comment: If `undefined` is cared about - you can always do `if (item.status)`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @tymeJV `if(item.status)` is not a good idea. For example: `var obj = { "status": 0 }` would evaluate false. `if(typeof obj.status !== 'undefined')` would be safer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`angular.isDefined` only test if the value is `undefined` :

```
function isDefined(value){return typeof value !== 'undefined';}
```

`Object.hasOwnProperty` test if the value is a direct one and not an inherited one.

For example :

```
var test = {};
angular.isDefined(test.toString); // true
test.hasOwnProperty('toString'); // false
```

info : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty